# OIDC client redirect to specific login provider at IdentityServer4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

So I have a basic Setup. IdentityServer with 3 login options. Username/Password, Google login and an External Login provider. As it is right now when I run the following code:

```
var config = {
    authority: "https://example.com",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "https://example.com/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://example.com/index.html",
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

function login() {
    mgr.signinRedirect();
}
```

I get redirected to the following page.

[image]

When I press login I get redirected to my login page:

[image]

This is all fine. But now I have a new requirement for the login process. They want a specific login button on the javascript client to start login with google and a specific button to login with OpenIDConnect login provider from the javascript Client.

So I could have some subpage eg. /GoogleIntegrations.html or whatever. And there I would like to have a button "Try google login", that should start loginflow with google, by redirect to the IdentityServer and then make the google redirect instantly afterwards.

Has anyone had similar usecase?

Edit1:

Account controller can be found here:
https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer/blob/master/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Controllers/Account/AccountController.cs

Edit2:
I have tried the solution by abdusco, but I am stuck on the identity server. I don't get redirected back to my Javascript client.

eg: If I have button with:
https://localhost:5001/External/Challenge?scheme=OpenIdConnect
I do get redirected to the external login provider. But when I login I am stuck on the Identity Server page.

I have also tried to login with the following link:

https://localhost:5001/External/Challenge?returnurl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=js&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5003%2Fcallback.html&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20api1&scheme=OpenIdConnect

GIF of how it looks with normal flow:

[image]

Edit3:

using the following code from comment:

```
var returnUrl = location.href;
var url = "https://localhost:5001/External/Challenge?returnurl=" + returnUrl + "&scheme=OpenIdConnect"
location.href = url;
```

throws exception. See code screenshot below

[image]

Edit4:

I was looking into another aproach, but still not entirely working as I want. On the login page on Identity, you can bypass username/password login. If I comment out that code and just redirect to my OpenIdConnect login. I get login and redirect back to client as I want, but this will then not allow me to use google or username password login.

Code looks like the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into the login workflow
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

        var context = HttpContext;

        //if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
        //{
            // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
            return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", 
                new { scheme = "OpenIdConnect", provider = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
        //}

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an `AccountController` in your project? Include it in your post

Comment: Account controller can be found here:
https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer/blob/master/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Controllers/Account/AccountController.cs
Made a dummy project to MVP  login :)

Comment: Can you post your Startup.cs where you set up authentication schemes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

So first off I created a new Callback URL for the OpenIDConnect Users. Eg. /admincallback.html

Then I can use the OIDC Usermanger javascript like so:

```
mgr.signinRedirect({ redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5003/admincallback.html' });
```

While normal login button just use the default /callback.html

This will let me check on the Identity backend what callback is being used and based on that what login page to show. Default or instant challenge external providers. Like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point into the login workflow
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
        var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

        if (returnUrl.Contains("admincallback"))
        {
            // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
            return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", 
                new { scheme = "OpenIdConnect", provider = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

You could create your callback url's to contain provider name like: /callback/google, /callback/oidc, /callback/azure, etc. This would let you dynamically decide which button was pressed. Instead of having a bunch of if statements for each supported provider.

This approach requires you to remember to add these new callback url's to the database. All code can be found here:

https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer

This is just a project where I share all IdentityServer related stuff I learn.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have `ExternalController.Challenge` method in your app,
create a URL that specifies the scheme, and you won't have to change anything.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// initiate roundtrip to external authentication provider
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Challenge(string scheme, string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "~/";

    // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) == false && _interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) == false)
    {
        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
    }
            
    // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(Callback)), 
        Items =
        {
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl }, 
            { "scheme", scheme },
        }
    };

    return Challenge(props, scheme);
            
}
```

```html
<a href="https://url/to/my/app/External/Challenge?scheme=Google">login with google</a>
```

---

Create an endpoint in your app, and issue a challenge for Google auth.

```cs
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("/login-google")]
    public ActionResult LoginGoogle()
    {
        return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalCallback"),
                // RedirectUri = Url.Page("LoginCallback"),
            }, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
}
```

Add a button, when clicked, redirect the user to this endpoint.
User will be forced to sign in to his Google account directly without showing the login view of your app.

```html
<button onclick="location.href='/login-google'">login with google</button>

<!-- or a simple anchor should suffice -->

<a href="/login-google">login with google</a>
```

Note that this the most basic setup. You must have an `AccountController` or `Login` razor page that contains the logic for what to do when the user returns from Google, so try setting the redirect URL to that action.

Comment: The javascript client is on a different domain than the identity server. Will give it a try anyway

Comment: You already have the code in place, see my edit https://github.com/TopSwagCode/Dotnet.IdentityServer/blob/master/src/IdentityServerAspNetIdentity/Controllers/Account/ExternalController.cs#L52-L76

Comment: @Kiksen check the link of `Google` button on the login page and redirect the user to that exact URL

Comment: The redirect url is as the following:
https://localhost:5003/callback.html&response_type=code&scope=openid profile api1&state=9346d159226648b680a3b6e18dccf407&code_challenge=Q1RRd5fq31Om6qcIk-rcfWuCRzRxyrXFwWy54ZjRiuo&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query"

Comment: I don't have the state. The state is different each time.

Comment: No not the redirect URL, right click the Google button and copy the address. It should have a `scheme=Google` query parameter.

Comment: I have tried with the Scheme. Problem is I am redirected to the IdentityServer on Port 5001 and not the Client that wanted to login on Port 5003, like I would normally.

Comment: specify the `returnUrl` parameter to redirect back to UI. add a `&returnUrl=...` parameter to the url (it should already have one, replace it) and set its value to `location.href`

Comment: I have tried what you said. Think I found another way of doing it.

Comment: Added new edit which still not entirely what I want.